# Popup command line on shortcut

Tags: macos, shortcut

On Windows, you can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and that pops up a small panel with a single line input box, where you can type anything, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the input will be processed by `cmd.exe`, i.e. roughly speaking the shell.

How can I do that on macOS, please?

Answer (score 1):

This does not exist as a part of macOS. The closest alternative is to simply launch the Terminal app. You can also launch Spotlight with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to access a lot of simple search features. You can read about the basics on [apple's website](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/spotlight-mchlp1008/mac). I also might recommend some third-party spotlight replacement apps such as [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) or quicksilver. You can use these apps to run commands in the terminal directly from <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you want to know some basic Terminal commands to replace what you are used to on Windows, I recommend the open command. You can use it to open a URL, a file, a folder, etc. For example, open a folder with `open /path/to/folder`. Open a file with `open file.txt` (you can also add `-a SomeApplicationHere` to open a file in a different app). Lastly, use `./your-script-here` to execute some script in the directory you are in.